# POST after a GET and consume it on Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I want to create a service which does a GET and a POST and use it on a component. What's the best way to do it?

**auth.service.ts**

```
getToken() {
    return this.http.get(this.getServerUrl() + '/token');
}

login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.getToken()
    .subscrive((response: Response) => {
        return this.http.post(this.getServerUrl() + '/login'
            , JSON.stringify({username: username, password: passowrd}))
    });
 }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
login(username, password) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.authService.login(username, password)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error.text());
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a promise for getting the token, then do the post after

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need this token once, the promise will return it once then carry out the http post

```
this.getToken()
.then(response=>{
if(response){
this.http.post ....
}
});
```